# Issues with Folium Grid Visualization in Xarray (Python)

Tags: python, folium

I'm working on a grid visualization using Folium and Xarray in Python. The code is designed to display rectangles on a map, representing grid cells with associated wind speeds. The visualization works well when zoomed in, but becomes problematic when zooming out – at certain zoom levels, the rectangles are not visible.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import xarray as xr
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import folium

# Specify the URL of the NetCDF file
url = "https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/socd/mecb/sar/AKDEMO_products/APL_winds/tropical/2024/SH052024_BELAL/STAR_SAR_20240116013937_SH052024_05S_MERGED_FIX_3km.nc"

# Download the NetCDF file content
response = requests.get(url)
nc_content = BytesIO(response.content)

# Open the NetCDF file using xarray
dataset = xr.open_dataset(nc_content)

# Access the 'sar_wind' variable
sar_wind = dataset['sar_wind'].values

# Get latitude and longitude information from the NetCDF file
latitude = dataset['latitude'].values
longitude = dataset['longitude'].values

# Calculate the resolution of each grid cell
lat_resolution = abs(latitude[0, 1] - latitude[0, 0])
lon_resolution = abs(longitude[1, 0] - longitude[0, 0])

# Create a Folium map centered around the mean latitude and longitude
mean_lat = latitude.mean()
mean_lon = longitude.mean()
mymap = folium.Map(location=[mean_lat, mean_lon], zoom_start=10)

# Define color levels based on wind speed
speed_levels = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20,30]
speed_colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red',"purple"]

r = 2
# Iterate through each point and add a larger rectangle to the map
for lat, lon, wind_speed in zip(latitude.flatten(), longitude.flatten(), sar_wind.flatten()):
    # Calculate rectangle bounds based on lat, lon, and resolution
    bounds = [(lat - r * lat_resolution, lon - r * lon_resolution),
              (lat + r * lat_resolution, lon + r * lon_resolution)]

    # Determine color based on wind speed level
    color_index = next((i for i, level in enumerate(speed_levels) if wind_speed <= level), len(speed_levels) - 1)
    color = speed_colors[color_index]


    # Add rectangle to the map with no borders
    folium.Rectangle(
        bounds=bounds,
        color=color,
        fill=True,
        fill_color=color,
        fill_opacity=0.6,
        weight=0,  # Set weight to 0 for no borders
        popup=f'Wind Speed: {wind_speed:.2f} m/s'
    ).add_to(mymap)

# Save the map as an HTML file or display it in Jupyter Notebook
mymap
```

Explanation:

I'm using Xarray to handle NetCDF data and Folium to create a map with rectangles representing grid cells. The rectangles are colored based on wind speed levels, and their size is dynamically adjusted.

[image]

Issue:

When zooming out on the map, the rectangles become too small to be visible. I'd like to find a solution to make the visualization more robust when zooming out, ensuring the rectangles are still visible.

Questions:

- Is there a way to dynamically adjust the size of the rectangles based on the zoom level to ensure visibility?
- Are there any alternative approaches or parameters that could enhance the visibility of the rectangles when zooming out?
- How to add contours ? as we can see in this image : https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/socd/mecb/sar/sarwinds_tropical.php?year=2024&storm=SH052024_BELAL

[image]